# How can i set data in ApplicationUser?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My `ApplicationUser` is extended with a virtual `UserData` class such as

```
public partial class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
  [IgnoreDataMember, NotMapped]
  public IEnumerable<UserData> UserData { get; set; }
}
```

How can i set the `UserData` when the user, logs in my application?

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
     var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);
     if (result.Succeeded)
     {
         var user = _context.Users.Where(x => x.Email == Input.Email).FirstOrDefault();
         using (myContext myContext = new myContext())
         {
               user.UserData = myContext.UserData.Where(x => x.UserId == user.Id);
         }
     }
}
```

So that the `UserData` will be already available for depedency injection at my controllers?
(I have set the data in the user variable above, for demonstration purposes)

Unfortunately setting `UserData` via `identity.AddClaim` is not an option and setting such values in session is not recommended

Comment: Have you tried to apply my answer?

Comment: @MuratYıldız answer seems to be correct

Comment: @OrElse what are you even trying to do, You cannot set an IQuerable as your userData `user.UserData = myContext.UserData.Where(x => x.UserId == user.Id)`

Comment: @johnny5 Thanks johnny5. I also edit my answer by adding some useful methods and explanations that are already tested and applied in some of the project where `ASP.NET Identity` is used.

Comment: @MuratYıldız Hello, i have not not tried yet and i will be honest. Actually i cannot quite understand how your answer is related to my issue

Comment: @johnny5 UserData is typeof DbSet<IQuerable>

Comment: @OrElse, UserData is an IEnumerable,  there is no explicitly call to materialize the data before the context is disposed of.  I'm pretty sure it would throw when the data is being accessed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I like to do in my projects is to have a separate `SessionService` (you can call it how you like) that is a scoped service where is stored all the user-related parameters and configurable information (for example his/her access level, preferred language, role, culture preferences, nationality, currency, etc.).

To initialize that service, I use an action filter and this is one example of that. To learn more about filter in ASP.Net Core, you can relate to their [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

```
    public class SessionFilter : IAsyncActionFilter
    {
        public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
        {
            if (context?.HttpContext == null) return;

            var services = context.HttpContext.RequestServices;
            var sessionProvider = services?.GetService<ISessionProvider>();
            if (sessionProvider == null) return;

            // Read the user identifier.
            var userRepository = services.GetService<IUserRepository>();
            Guid userId = default;

            var claims = context.HttpContext.User?.Claims;
            var idClaim = claims?.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == RequestData.ID_CLAIM)?.Value;
            if (userRepository != null && Guid.TryParse(idClaim, out var id))
            {
                var getUserInfo = await userRepository.EnsureExistsAsync(id, context.HttpContext.RequestAborted).ConfigureAwait(false);

                if (getUserInfo.Data && getUserInfo.Success)
                    userId = id;
            }

            // Read the preferred language.
            var headers = context.HttpContext.Request?.Headers;
            var preferredLanguage = string.Empty;

            if (headers != null && headers.TryGetValue(RequestData.LANGUAGE_HEADER, out var preferredLanguageHeader))
                preferredLanguage = preferredLanguageHeader.FirstOrDefault();

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(preferredLanguage)) preferredLanguage = UserConfigurationParameters.DEFAULT_LANGUAGE;

            // Configure the current session.
            sessionProvider.ConfigureSession(userId, preferredLanguage);

            await next();
        }
    }
```

And that is the actual SessionService (here it is called ISessionProvider).

```
    public class SessionProvider : ISessionProvider
    {
        public SessionProvider()
        {
            this.PreferredLanguage = string.Empty;
        }

        public bool AllowReconfiguration { get; private set; }
        public bool IsConfigured { get; private set; }
        public Guid UserId { get; private set; }
        public string PreferredLanguage { get; private set; }

        public void ConfigureSession(Guid userId, string preferredLanguage, bool allowReconfiguration = false)
        {
            if (this.AllowReconfiguration == false && this.IsConfigured) throw new InvalidOperationException(ErrorMessages.SessionCannotBeReconfigured);

            this.UserId = userId;
            this.PreferredLanguage = preferredLanguage;

            this.IsConfigured = true;
            this.AllowReconfiguration = allowReconfiguration;
        }
    }
```

This way you can pass data about the user to every layer in your application thanks to the Dependency injection mechanism in ASP.

Comment: Action filters are not applied before and after every controller execution? You see, I wish to read data once

Comment: I think that you should consider this part. If you read data once, how can you update it if it is internally changed. For example - an admin removes the user, blocks him/her, resets his password, etc... Action filters are applied before every controller action so it is easy to maintain and validate the data integrity.

Comment: One more thing to think about is what should happen when hundreds, thousands, millions of people start using that app at the same time.

Comment: Hello Tony, thank you for your efforts. All these data you mention reside on the ApplicationUser class, so such admin changes won't be an issue. The userData class is about two maybe three properties

Comment: in this case another thing that may be a solution for that problem is to store that information in cache, There are various types of cache you can use depending on your needs. So generally versus every user's identifier, you can store that information and the read it when necessary. That logic again can be separated in a service that should be injected wherever needed.

Answer (score 1):

> You might try something like that:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(string username, int id)
{
    // get by username
    ApplicationUser user = UserManager.FindByName(username);

    // get by user id
    ApplicationUser user = db.Users.Find(id);

    // get current user
    ApplicationUser user = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext()
        .GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>().FindById(Convert
        .ToInt32(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId()));

    // and some other useful methods        
    if (user == null)
    {
        // creating user 
        user = new ApplicationUser();

        // fill in the user properties 
        user.UserName = "johnny";
        user.Name = "Johnny English";
        //...
        var result = UserManager.Create(user);

        // set default user group and roles
        var defaultGroup = "xxxx-yyyy-zzzz-tttt"; // Id of the ApplicationGroup
        groupManager.SetUserGroups(user.Id, new string[] { defaultGroup });
        groupManager.SetGroupRoles(newGroup.Id, new string[] { role.Name });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `ICurrentUserData` interface and get the user data from your context in the implementation.

```
public interface ICurrentUserData
{
    public IEnumerable<UserData> UserData { get; }

}

public class CurrentUserData : ICurrentUserData
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    private readonly myContext _context;
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

    public CurrentUserData(myContext context, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _context = context;
        _userManager = userManager;
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    private List<UserData> _userData;

    public IEnumerable<UserData> UserData 
    {
        get
        {
            if (_userData == null)
            {
                using (myContext myContext = new myContext())
                {
                    _userData = myContext.UserData.Where(x => x.UserId == _userManager.GetUserId(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User)).ToList();
                }

            }
            return _userData;
        }
    }
}
```

You should register them in your startup as Scope so you get one user data per request.

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddScoped<ICurrentUserData, CurrentUserData>();
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    }
}
```